Did the sahaba pray with hands on side?
Assalamu alaikum wa rahmatullah, a maliki argued with me that some sahaba prayed with their hands on side, he mentioned these sahahba : -‘Abdullah ibn Zubayr [s/o -Sayyiduna Zubayr and -Sayyidatuna Asma bint Abi Bakr]
-Muhammad al-Baqir
-Ja’far as-Sadiq
-Musa al-Khadhim
-Hasan al-Basri [Student of Imam ‘Ali]
-an-Nakha’i [tabi’i and student of ‘Abdullah ibn Abbas]
-Layth ibn Sa’ad [teacher of Imam as-Sahfi’i who said about him – ‘kana afqah min Malik – ‘He was more learned than Malik’]
-Imam al-Awzai [Mujtahid Imam of ahlus-Shaam whose madhab died out]
-ibn al-Qasim
-ibn Abu’l HakamIs
He Provided evidence for one and it follows :
Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaybah (Volume 1, Page 391, Hadith 3946): It is narrated that some of the companions, including Abdullah ibn Zubayr and Sa'id ibn al-Musayyib, prayed with their hands at their sides. The report goes:
"عَنِ ابْنِ جُرَيْجٍ قَالَ: كَانَ ابْنُ الزُّبَيْرِ إِذَا صَلَّى تَرَكَ يَدَيْهِ، وَلَمْ يَضَعْ إِحْدَاهُمَا عَلَى الْأُخْرَى."
Translation: Ibn Jurayj said: "When Ibn Zubayr prayed, he would leave his hands (by his sides) and not place one of them over the other."
Please tell me if any of those companions including Abdullah ibn zubayr praying with hands on side is authentic or not. jazakAllahu khayrann

I covered this in my answer on Is there a hadith for the maliki way of praying if you agree and accept then accept that post as duplicate,
